# button click not working first time in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

This is my html code

```
 < button class="send-report" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" onclick="reportfeed()">Send Report< /button>
```

On the first click the keyboard disappeared, the 'reportfeed' function works only in the second click (in ipad)

```
function reportfeed()
{
alert(1);
}
```

I can use the code below, Please help me if you know any other method

```
jQuery(".send-report").bind("click touchstart", function(){
reportfeed();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a clickhandler that you can use later on:

```
var clickHandler = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? "touchstart" : "click");

$(".send-report").bind(clickHandler, function(e) {
    alert("clicked or tapped. This button used: " + clickHandler);
});
```

This will trigger click on non-touch devices and touchstart on touch devices.

Use `.on()` because `.bind()` will be removed from future scripts,I think.

Comment: @sijo vijayan did you get the solution

Comment: Why did you tell this as not a perfect solution...?

Comment: Because i am using same issues in different pages and different buttons (in class name), so i need to rewrite your code in each page for each button,

Comment: @sijovijayan put the code inside a function and call it wherever it is required..

Comment: Dude, I have 5 year experience in web development and programming.

I know how to do this, I have tried all possible simplest methods. I am working with social engine [zend framework]. It is little complex call this as a function to all pages. because of some complex widgets rendering system.

Comment: I believe this is a definition of a perfect solution, and @sijovijayan is just being lazy and perhaps even arrogant.

Comment: One small thing - you don't need the parenthesis around the ternary :)

Comment: @NinoŠkopac, I wasn't lazy or arrogant, but it was a very frustrating situation for me because of lots of similar issues in that project. @_Techy, I apologize to you unconditionally, I admit that, it is not a relevant way to talk to someone who is trying to help me without any profit.

Comment: @sijovijayan Its ok...Go well ahead

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".send-report").on('touchstart click', function(){
 reportfeed();
});
```

You could use .stopPropagation() to stop multiple events being fired. Also, if you want to do specific stuff for different event types use e.type

```
 $('.send-report').on('touchstart click', function(e) {    
    e.stopPropagation(); //stops propagation
    if(e.type == "touchstart") {
      // Handle touchstart event.
    } else if(e.type == "click") {
       // Handle click event.
    }
   });
```